# Any way to bypass the Android 8kHz sampling limit of bluetooth audio input?

Tags: android

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#startBluetoothSco%28%29

```
The following restrictions apply on input streams:

the format must be mono
the sampling must be 8kHz
```

For years now the bluetooth audio input stream on Android has been set at an abysmally low sampling rate of 8kHz which is the old Headset Profile (HSP), but Bluetooth audio now is capable of much higher sampling rates. A2DP is from 16 to 48kHz. Is there any way to program around this limit in Android so that high quality wireless bluetooth microphone recording will become feasible?

Comment: did you find out anything about this?